# code printing "n" instead of "if". I don't know why this is happening

Tags: python, string, replace

(My problem) When I input "ad" into this program, it outputs "n". I want to move each character forward 5 characters in the alphabet ("ad" would become "fi"), and then reverse the outcome ("fi" would become "if").

```
print("This program is meant to allow users to securely store text information through the use of different forms of security measures.")




IA=input("Enter the information you would like stored:")
#creating/opening a text file and inserting/storing the user input
a=open("user_input","wt")
a.write(IA)
a=open("user_input","rt")
print(a.read())
a.close()


print("Enter the different ways you would like the information entered. It is recommended you use more than just 1 of these methods for security")
SFA=input("Would you like the information to be stored using encryption?(Answer in 'yes' or 'no'):")

#creating a list
thislist = ["SFA","SFB","SFC","SFD","SFE"]
if SFA:"yes"
RT=IA




RT=RT.replace("f","0").replace("a",chr(ord("a")+5)).replace("f","1").replace("0","f")
RT=RT.replace("g","2").replace("b",chr(ord("b")+5)).replace("g","3").replace("2","g")
RT=RT.replace("h","4").replace("c",chr(ord("c")+5)).replace("h","5").replace("4","h")
RT=RT.replace("i","6").replace("d",chr(ord("d")+5))
RT=RT.replace("i","7").replace("6","i").replace("j","8").replace("e",chr(ord("e")+5))
RT=RT.replace("j","9").replace("8","j").replace("k","10").replace("f",chr(ord("f")+5))
RT=RT.replace("k","11").replace("l","12").replace("g",chr(ord("g")+5)).replace("10","k").replace("3","g")
RT=RT.replace("l","13").replace("m","14").replace("h",chr(ord("h")+5)).replace("5","h").replace("12","l")
RT=RT.replace("m","15").replace("n","16").replace("14","m").replace("i",chr(ord("i")+5))
RT=RT.replace("n","17").replace("16","n").replace("o","18").replace("j",chr(ord("j")+5))
RT=RT.replace("o","19").replace("18","o").replace("p","20").replace("k",chr(ord("k")+5)).replace("11","k")
RT=RT.replace("p","21").replace("20","p").replace("q","22").replace("l",chr(ord("l")+5)).replace("13","l")
RT=RT.replace("q","23").replace("22","q").replace("r","24").replace("m",chr(ord("m")+5)).replace("15","m")
RT=RT.replace("r","25").replace("24","r").replace("s","26").replace("n",chr(ord("n")+5)).replace("17","n").replace("7","i")
RT=RT.replace("s","27").replace("26","s").replace("t","28").replace("o",chr(ord("o")+5)).replace("19","o").replace("9","j")
RT=RT.replace("t","29").replace("28","t").replace("u","30").replace("p",chr(ord("p")+5)).replace("21","p")
RT=RT.replace("u","31").replace("30","u").replace("v","32").replace("q",chr(ord("q")+5)).replace("23","q")
RT=RT.replace("v","33").replace("32","v").replace("w","34").replace("r",chr(ord("r")+5)).replace("25","r")
RT=RT.replace("w","35").replace("34","w").replace("x","36").replace("s",chr(ord("s")+5)).replace("27","s")
RT=RT.replace("x","37").replace("36","x").replace("y","38").replace("t",chr(ord("t")+5)).replace("29","t")
RT=RT.replace("y","39").replace("38","y").replace("z","40").replace("u",chr(ord("u")+5)).replace("31","u")
RT=RT.replace("z","41").replace("40","z").replace("a","42").replace("v",chr(ord("v")-21)).replace("33","v")
RT=RT.replace("a","43").replace("42","a").replace("b","42").replace("w",chr(ord("w")-21)).replace("35","w").replace("43","a")
RT=RT.replace("b","45").replace("44","b").replace("c","44").replace("x",chr(ord("x")-21)).replace("37","x").replace("45","b")
RT=RT.replace("c","47").replace("46","c").replace("d","46").replace("y",chr(ord("y")-21)).replace("39","y").replace("47","c")
RT=RT.replace("d","49").replace("48","d").replace("e","44").replace("z",chr(ord("z")-21)).replace("41","z").replace("49","d").replace("1","f")
rtback = RT[::-1]
print(rtback)
```

Comment: This is an overcomplicated encoding method, putting that to side, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the problems is because you can't know when is 1 and 7 or when is 17. You have to split your letters and operate them individually.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, do you think I could use different characters for this, like using "[" for 17 for example?

Comment: I think you will still having problems like if you have 2122 I belive it will replace the 12 in between 21 and 22 for 'l', but I'm not so sure. Operating letters individually is the most secure way of avoiding this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code to using random sybmols instead of numbers, such as for example "Ç" for 7, and using "€" for 17. Tested it many times now it works great!